# Set a Default Value for a dropdown in ADF

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf

In a jsff file a component has been designed and the values are being fetched from a Static VO. There are only two values in the static Vo. I need the first option to be set as default. But there is a empty value that is being set. I have written a condition to disable it. And when it is disabled the value must be set to the first one.

I have tried the List UI Hints and tried to enable the Include No selection item: Labeled Item first of list, I tried creating a new vo which only has one value and rendered it in Jsff(But it will make the code more complex for the future development) I have tried creating the switcher. But none of them worked as they should.

Can anyone suggest me a alternative where the code complexity does not increase and by default there is a first value selected. And disable if there is condition for disable tag in jsff is true.

PS: Once the  field is disabled the first value must be the default value to be set by default.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value for the VO attribute on which you are building list?

Answer (score 1):

There don't seem to be any default way to do this with Oracle ADF without adding code to your view Object. Here's how to automatically select First value in your ADF LOV (detail from here https://cedricleruth.com/autoselect-first-value-in-adf-lov-inside-a-table/) :

- Generate the RowImpl Java class of your View Object and Static VO
- In this RowImpl.java add the following function to return the first value if no value is already selected

```java
public String defaultNextStatus() {
 String value = (String) getAttributeInternal(AttributesEnum.NextStatus.index());
 if (value == null) {
  XxcrWorkflowUvVORowImpl nextStatut = (XxcrWorkflowUvVORowImpl) getWfkVA().first(); 
  //Wkfva is the VO of the LOV
  if (nextStatut != null) {
   return nextStatut.getTxtValeur();
  }
 }
 return value;
}
```

- In the Detail panel of the attribute add the following Default Value Expression: adf.object.defaultNextStatus()
- In the Detail panel of the attribute set the refresh Expression Value to false to avoid picking the first value again in case of ppr/refresh

Comment: The disable part must be handle using the jsff condition regardless :)